# Simple c++ constructor don't work (very basic)

Tags: c++

Ok, so I've decided to read a little c++ now and then, just to get a basic understanding of the syntax. I am familiar with Java, and a little bit of Python. I have 'read' through a c++ for dummies book, and I thought I had the grip - until I tried to create the simplest class. 
The idea was *very* simple: a class (named ape) takes one parameter, an int, which is stored as a private field. It has one other function, a return function, which returns the field. The main() creates an instance, and calls the method to print out the variable.

The idea was to use a string instead of an int, but I couldn't get it working, so I decided to use an int instead, which, obviously, wasn't working either.

If it is to any interest I use Code::blocks, Windows 7 and the g++ compiler.

Here are the classes:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ape.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ape asd(10);
    cout << asd.getNumber();
}
```

ape.h

```
#ifndef APE_H
#define APE_H

class ape
{
    public:
        ape(int num);
        virtual ~ape();
        int getNumber();
    protected:
    private:
        int number;
};

#endif // APE_H
```

and ape.cpp

```
#include "ape.h"
using namespace std;

ape::ape(int num)
{
    tall = num;
}

ape::~ape()
{
    //dtor
}

int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
```

The error messages I get seems very random to me, as they are changing completely with every single change I make, and are not very self explaining. I can see how I sound like an arrogant fool, and that this whole mess is the compilers fault, but I really don't see any connection between the error messages and what's wrong in my code.

Take it easy on me, first time here. :)

I guess I should probably add the error message: 
*undefined reference to 'ape::ape(int)'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to a variable that doesn't exist.

Change:

```
ape::ape(int num)
{
    tall = num;
}
```

To:

```
ape::ape(int num) :
  number(num)
{
}
```

Moreover, I don't know why you wrote a destructor, and why you decided to make it `virtual`. By default, the compiler will generate an empty destructor (similar to yours, but not `virtual`). If you don't intend to do polymorphism (with inheritance and all that "stuff"), you may delete this destructor from your code as it only brings complexity for no gain.

You also need to prefix your method **definitions** with the name of the class:

```
int ape::getNumber() // Note the "ape::" here
{
    return number;
}
```

One last thing:

You problably want to change also your `main`:

```
int main()
{
    ape asd(10);
    cout << asd.getNumber() << endl;
}
```

Something put into `cout` only gets printed when one outputs `endl` or `flush` as the stream is buffered.

Regarding your last edit:

> I guess I should probably add the error message: undefined reference
>   to 'ape::ape(int)'

You probably failed to link with `ape.o`. In your compilation folder, you should have your source files and a `.o` for every `.cpp`. You have to link those **object files** together to build your program. This message indicates that the linker is unable to find the definition for `ape::ape(int)`. That is he was probably not given the `ape.o` file.

Long story short, here is what your compilation commands should look like (using g++):

```
g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o ape.o -c ape.cpp
g++ -o program main.o ape.o
```

Comment: This was just Code::blocs automaking of the files. I guess I could've unchecked the option to have a destructor, but I didn't bother.

Comment: @MartinHaTh Oh I see. I don't use Code::Blocks. The other points stand still ;) Hope this can help.

Comment: The commands did the trick. I guess it's Code::blocks fault, then. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Not much to say without the actual error messages, but at least here is a problem:

```
int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
```

This should be `int ape::getNumber()`. Also in your code there is no definition for `tall`, should perhaps be `number` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are using undeclared field "tall". Seems like your constructor should be:

```
ape::ape(int num)
{
    number = num;
}
```

Comment: Always use initialiser list to initialise fields.

Comment: Oh, well, my bad, I'm writing my field- and function names partly in Norwegian, for simplicity's sake, and I guess I missed that one. I was changing all the names before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

```
ape::ape(int num)
{
    tall = num;
}
```

tall? Where did `tall` come from? The member was declared as `number`.

Better would be

```
ape::ape(int num) { number = num; }
```

Much better would be

```
ape::ape(int num) : number(num) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is tall? The private field is called number in your example, so this function:

```
ape::ape(int num)
{
    tall = num;
}
```

should be:

```
ape::ape(int num)
{
    number = num;
}
```

However, in C++ you should use initialization and not assignments. While for an int is not a big deal, for more complex objects assignment is more expensive as you are copying the object, while with initialization you can use the copy constructor. Therefore the convention is to initialize all variables before the body of the constructor.

```
ape::ape(int num)
  : number(num)
{
}
```

And, please declare getNumber() as a const method. Here you have a nice guide explaining all the const variants: http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/cpp-pitfalls.html

While you are at it, add the missing class prefix, which you need if you are defining the method outside of the declaration of the class:

```
int ape::getNumber() const
{
    return number;
}
```

As a last comment, I recommend you look for a convention on naming member variables. Typical  are mNumber or _number. Makes reading your own code easier later on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set variable `number` in constructor, before you can read it in `getNumber`. 
Try this:

```
ape::ape(int num)
{
    number = num;
}
```